# How to convert HEVC videos from Photos to h264 on iOS?

Tags: ios, encoding, avasset, avassetexportsession, hevc

I've been looking into the Apple documentation but I couldn't find anything that would allow me to convert a video recorded on an iPhone 7 (HEVC) to h264.
I need to do this because the app has a web server running and it's streaming the video to web browsers that don't support HEVC.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this, facing same.